# Separate Messaging system Inside Bounded Context

Tags: events, rabbitmq, domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

Is it a good practice to run a separate Messaging system for internal Domain Events inside Bounded Context? Or It's better to reuse the common one, which is listened by all bounded contexts?
Check out images to understand the question better:

Option one (Common RAbbitMq for all contexts:
[image: Option one (Common RAbbitMq for all contexts)]

Option two (Separate RabbitMq for each BC):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first approach is totally valid. The bounded contexts are abstractions to encapsulate domain or business logic related to one context of the business however the message system is a piece that only exixts to facilitate the communication between these decoupled and hermetic bounded context so, I think that have a unique message broker shared by multiple bounded context is correct. In addition this way you will have less overhead and latency